# Enum in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, enums

If I understood correctly, there is no `enum` in Javascript/Google Scripts (I'm a Javascript novice, so I know just the basics of it). To overcome this, one can define a list of constants, like:

```
const COLUMNS_INDEXES
{
  FIRST_NAME: 1,
  LAST_NAME: 2,
  ADDRESS: 3
}
```

As suggested by this example, I need to define the columns indexes of various entries in a Spreadsheet, so I can access them via constants and have a more readable/editable code.

Needing to manually set every entry is quite annoying and, more important, prone to mistake. Also, when I need to insert a new column between two existing ones, I need to edit all the following entries (more annoying, more risk of errors). Example:

```
const COLUMNS_INDEXES
{
  FIRST_NAME: 1,
  NICKNAME: 2,
  LAST_NAME: 3,
  ADDRESS: 4
}
```

A good solution to this could have been to declare the list like this:

```
const COLUMNS_INDEXES
{
  FIRST_NAME: 1,
  LAST_NAME: FIRST_NAME + 1,
  ADDRESS: LAST_NAME + 1
}
```

This way when I insert a new entry I just need to edit a couple of lines, and all the following ones gets "automatically updated":

```
const COLUMNS_INDEXES
{
  FIRST_NAME: 1,
  NICKNAME: FIRST_NAME + 1,
  LAST_NAME: NICKNAME+ 1,
  ADDRESS: LAST_NAME + 1
}
```

Awfully, this syntax generates an error... Same if I fully reference the entries, like `LAST_NAME: COLUMNS_INDEXES.FIRST_NAME + 1`.

So, the question is: Is there a smart way to declare enums/consts without needing to set the value of every entry?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: `when I need to insert a new column between two existing ones` Spreadsheet Developer metadata is worth considering in this case.

Comment: @TheMaster This looks interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following sample script:

#### Sample script 1:

```js
const COLUMNS_INDEXES = {
  FIRST_NAME: 1,
  get NICKNAME() { return this.FIRST_NAME + 1 },
  get LAST_NAME() { return this.NICKNAME + 1 },
  get ADDRESS() { return this.LAST_NAME + 1 },
};

console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES.FIRST_NAME); // 1
console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES.NICKNAME); // 2
console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES.LAST_NAME); // 3
console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES.ADDRESS); // 4
console.log(JSON.stringify(COLUMNS_INDEXES)); // {"FIRST_NAME":1,"NICKNAME":2,"LAST_NAME":3,"ADDRESS":4}
```

- In this case, the values of `COLUMNS_INDEXES.NICKNAME`, `COLUMNS_INDEXES.LAST_NAME`, `COLUMNS_INDEXES.NICKNAME`, and `COLUMNS_INDEXES.ADDRESS` are 2, 3, 4, and 5, respectively.

#### Sample script 2:

```js
const keys = ["FIRST_NAME", "NICKNAME", "LAST_NAME", "ADDRESS"];
const COLUMNS_INDEXES = keys.reduce((o, e, i) => (o[e] = i + 1, o), {});
console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES); // { FIRST_NAME: 1, NICKNAME: 2, LAST_NAME: 3, ADDRESS: 4 }
```

#### Sample script 3:

```js
const keys = ["FIRST_NAME", "NICKNAME", "LAST_NAME", "ADDRESS"];
const COLUMNS_INDEXES = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((e, i) => [e, i + 1]));
console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES); // { FIRST_NAME: 1, NICKNAME: 2, LAST_NAME: 3, ADDRESS: 4 }
```

Comment: Given my familiarity with C++, I understand your first script, and it can be a good solution. Have to look more carefully on the other 2 examples.

Comment: @il_mix Thank you for replying. In the 1st sample, for example, you can set freely `+ 1` to `+ 3` and `* 2` and so on as the customize. In the 2nd and 3rd samples, it assumes that each value of keys is increased one by one. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I somehow grasped the functionality of samples 2 and 3. It's just that I'm not used to use keys/id pairs. As an example, I see that you can `console.log()` the entire COLUMNS_INDEXES and get the list printed. But how to access a single value from within a function? Like, if I need COLUMNS_INDEXES.FIRST_NAME in my function, how do I get it?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out by blind testing. I need to call `console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES["NICKNAME"])`

Comment: @il_mix Thank you for replying. I think that `console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES["NICKNAME"])` and `console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES.NICKNAME)` return the same value.

Comment: @il_mix As another approach, I think that the Map object might be able to be used. In this case, you can also use `const COLUMNS_INDEXES = new Map(["FIRST_NAME", "NICKNAME", "LAST_NAME", "ADDRESS"].map((e, i) => [e, i + 1]));`. In this case, each value can be retrieved by `console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES.get("FIRST_NAME"));`, `console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES.get("NICKNAME"));`, `console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES.get("LAST_NAME"));`, `console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES.get("ADDRESS"));`. And, all values are retrieved by `console.log(Object.fromEntries([...COLUMNS_INDEXES]))`.

Comment: That's right! `console.log(COLUMNS_INDEXES.NICKNAME)` gives the same result. The syntax will be the same as using "standard" enums (my first example), and that's  a plus.

Answer (score 2):

### RECOMMENDED SOLUTION

Try reading through the different methods of [array manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods) that's available on the internet, as they can help you accomplish what you'd like. I also created a sample script using Google Apps Script for you to easily declare your objects in the order that you'll put them.

### SAMPLE SCRIPT

```
const COLUMNS_INDEXES = () => {
  var indexes = {};
  var index = 1;
  var addIndex = (name) => {
    indexes[name] = index++;
  };
  addIndex('FIRST_NAME');
  addIndex('LAST_NAME');
  addIndex('ADDRESS');

  console.log(indexes);
}
```

### OUTPUT

[image]

### UPDATE

This is an example of how you can access the first name in the function.

```
const COLUMNS_INDEXES = () => {
  var indexes = {};
  var index = 1;
  var addIndex = (name) => {
    indexes[name] = index++;
  };
  addIndex('FIRST_NAME');
  addIndex('NICKNAME');
  addIndex('LAST_NAME');
  addIndex('ADDRESS');

  return indexes;
};
const columnIndexes = COLUMNS_INDEXES();
console.log(columnIndexes.FIRST_NAME);
```

### OUTPUT

[image: OUTPUT2]

Comment: Looks functional and clean. `console.log()` is printing all values from within COLUMNS_INDEXES. But how can I access, as an example, to COLUMNS_INDEXES.FIRST_NAME from another function? Do I need to create a COLUMNS_INDEXES object first? Sorry for bothering you with basic questions, but, as said, I'm quite new to Javascript

Comment: That's alright. I'd be happy to help! As for `how can I access, as an example, to COLUMNS\_INDEXES.FIRST\_NAME from another function?` You are correct that you can `create a COLUMNS\_INDEXES object first` to access it. I've updated my answer as well with an example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the sample. Regarding your proposal, In my opinion the need to reconstruct the consts object any time I need it in a function is quite a downside. I need to do extra computation, and also need an extra line every time.